# java regular expression help

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to replace all the characters between an html font tag with an expression.   I wrote a little test program but it is not working correcty.   Here is my regular expression:

```
test.replaceAll("<font\b(.*)>", "Something");
```

This does not work.

Why?

Comment: What isn't working?  Is it not replacing anything?  Replacing too much?

Comment: can you provide an example of source text and desired output?

Comment: You can also play around with experimental regexes at http://refiddle.com which might help nail down the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the `*` operator is [*greedy*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), i.e.,

```
String test = "<font size=\"10\"><b>hello</b></font>";
System.out.println(test.replaceAll("<font\\b(.*)>", "Something"));
```

prints

```
Something
```

You may want to use `[^>]*`

```
test.replaceAll("<font\\b([^>]*)>", "Something")
```

or a *reluctant quantifier*, `*?`:

```
test.replaceAll("<font\\b(.*?)>", "Something")
```

which both result in

```
Something<b>hello</b></font>
```

Comment: Yep.   This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want two "\" before the "b":

```
test.replaceAll("<font\\b(.*)>", "Something");
```

You need this because the regular expression is a string and backslashes need to be escaped in strings.

To make it only match up to the first ">", do this:

```
test.replaceAll("<font\\b(.*?)>", "Something");
```

This makes the `*` "lazy", so that it matches as little as possible rather than as much as possible.

However, it seems that it is better to write this particular expression as follows:

```
test.replaceAll("<font\\b([^>]*)>", "Something");
```

This has the same effect and avoids backtracking, which should improve performance.

Comment: Yay for the quirkyness of Java and requiring you to escape slashes in a regex.  For reference, in Java `\\b` would be the word boundary match, `\\\\b` would match a literal `\b`.

Comment: My favorite example is matching a backslash: you need "\\\\" for one.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis: Whoops, I was editing my comment to clarify why this works when you posted your last comment.

Comment: putting the second slash in does help but now it wipes out everything else in the expression after the font tag and replaces it with "Something"    Is there a way to replace everything in the expression from the beginning of the <font to the First >?

Comment: Don't use the greedy dot-star! use `[^>]*`

Comment: @Tikhon: Yes, that’s a Java regex library flaw. Many of us who care about such things as simplicity of regexes long ago wrote a super-simple front-end to the Pattern class that lets you use normal slashes instead of backslashes, thus allowing things like `/w+` for a 7-bit ASCII word, `/s+` for 7-bit whitespace — and of course, simply `/` for a literal backslash. It’s a touch weird at first, but infinitely preferable to the error-prone aggravation of *How many backslashes does it take to get to the center of a tootsie-roll pop?* Too many hours lost debugging ever to go back to raw Java regexes.